# Maximizing tcp connection rate from haproxy to jetty application server

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp, jetty, haproxy

I'm using haproxy front-ended with nginx to loadbalance across jetty application servers, all running ubuntu-14-04-x64.

Nginx and haproxy share a 0.5G 1CPU VM. Each jetty server runs on a 4G 2CPU VM.

Nginx front-ends haproxy, configured like this:

```
user myc;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 65536;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    proxy_cache_path /home/myc/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:10m inactive=7d;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server unix:/tmp/haproxy.sock;
        keepalive 8192;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 backlog=16384;
        server_name example.org;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css application/json;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;

        open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 60s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors off;

        sendfile on;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        error_page 502 /502.html;
        location /502.html {
            root /home/myc/html;
        }

        proxy_cache one;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            add_header Cache-Control private; # Don't cache any of this publicly, because JSESSIONID will be cached, too

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/api;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_hide_header Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; # Make sure JSESSIONID is not cached with static content
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;

            proxy_cache_valid 200 10s;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        location ~* ^.*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer$uri;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            expires 1h;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;

            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_hide_header Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; # Make sure JSESSIONID is not cached with static content
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            proxy_cache_valid 200 404 10s;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }
    }
}
```

HAProxy is configured like this:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 262144
    maxconnrate 128
    chroot /home/jail/

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 120s
    timeout server 120s
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    compression algo identity
    option http-keep-alive

frontend http-in
    bind /tmp/haproxy.sock user myc
    default_backend makeyourcase

backend makeyourcase
    option httpchk GET /
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 1h
    server ny2-b-app01 <redacted>:8080 maxconn 1024 check inter 60000 fall 1 rise 1
    server ny2-b-app02 <redacted>:8080 maxconn 1024 check inter 60000 fall 1 rise 1
```

The TCP stack is tuned with these parms on the nginx/haproxy box and the two jetty boxes:

```
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65535
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0

net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 16777216

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
```

I'm using The Grinder to create load. Once the load builds to a certain point, SYN_SENT stacks up on the haproxy side. If I reduce `maconnrate` to 96, that reduces the connection rate enough that the SYN_SENTs never stack up. The back ends are never loaded beyond 20% CPU, and never over a load average of 1. I've tried a variety of tuning options in nginx, haproxy, and the tcp stack.

It seems that there might be some tcp parm that would let more connections/second come in to the jetty servers, and that would let haproxy fully load up the jetty servers.

OTOH, according to http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html, "By default HAProxy operates in keep-alive mode with regards to persistent
connections." And yet, the connections between haproxy and the app servers are not kept open. Is there some haproxy option I've specified that's preventing that? Or is there some option that would enable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I spent some time tweeking settings, shown below, the change that finally gave more reasonable results (about 14K simultaneous connections) was to bump the size of the VM hosting nginx and haproxy from 0.5G 1CPU to 2G 2CPU.

Here's the current nginx config:

```
user myc;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 131072;

events {
    worker_connections 65536;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    proxy_cache_path /home/myc/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:10m inactive=7d;

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server unix:/tmp/haproxy.sock;
        keepalive 32768;
    }

    upstream haproxy_admin {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 backlog=16384;
        server_name makeyourcase.org;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css application/json;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;

        open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 60s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors off;

        sendfile on;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        error_page 502 /502.html;
        location /502.html {
            root /home/myc/html;
        }

        proxy_cache one;

        location ~ ^/api/auth/local/.*$ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer$uri;
        }

        location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/admin;
        }

        location /stats {
            proxy_pass http://haproxy_admin/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            add_header Cache-Control private; # Don't cache any of this publicly, because JSESSIONID will be cached, too

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/api;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_hide_header Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; # Make sure JSESSIONID is not cached with static content
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;

            proxy_cache_valid 200 10s;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        location ~* ^.*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer$uri;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;

            expires 1h;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;

            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_hide_header Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; # Make sure JSESSIONID is not cached with static content
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            proxy_cache_valid 200 404 10s;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }
    }
}
```

And HAProxy:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 32768
    maxconnrate 256
    chroot /home/jail/

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 120s
    timeout server 120s
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    compression algo identity

frontend http-in
    bind /tmp/haproxy.sock user myc
    default_backend makeyourcase

backend makeyourcase
    option httpchk GET /
    option http-server-close
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 1h
    server ny2-b-app01 <redacted>:8080 maxconn 1024 check inter 60000 fall 1 rise 1
    server ny2-b-app02 <redacted>:8080 maxconn 1024 check inter 60000 fall 1 rise 1

listen stats localhost:8081
    mode   http
    stats  enable
    stats  hide-version
    stats  realm MYC
    stats  uri /
```

And sysctl:

```
fs.file-max = 1048576

net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 250000
net.core.somaxconn = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 134217728
net.core.wmem_max = 134217728

net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 67108864
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 67108864
net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1

vm.swappiness = 0
```